# Replace all occurrences in a String by using regex in groovy

Tags: regex, groovy, multiple-matches

When there are only one occurrence my code works:

```
def result = "Text 1,1"
def matches = (result =~ /^.+\s([0-9],[0-9])$/ ).with { m -> m.matches() ? result.replace(/${m[ 0 ][ 1 ]}/, 'X'+m[ 0 ][ 1 ]+'X') : result }
assert "Text X,X" == matches
```

How can I do if my String contains several occurrences?

```
def result = "aaaa Text 1,1 Text 2,2 ssss"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could replace the above with:

```
def matches = result.replaceAll( /[0-9],[0-9]/, 'X,X' )
```

Or, you could do:

```
def result = "aaaa Text 1,1 Text 2,2 ssss"

result = result.replaceAll( /[0-9],[0-9]/ ) { m -> "X${m}X" }

assert result == 'aaaa Text X1,1X Text X2,2X ssss'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I had simplified my code. In fact I need to retrieve the matched value (m[0][1]), perform some modification on it and replace it (instead of 'X,X').